Squid 5.9 on Ubuntu 22.04LTS unable to authen using Windows 2022 AD Server
Environment:
Squid OS: Ubuntu 22.04LTS
Squid version: 5.9
Windows DC OS: Windows Server 2022 Standard
Windows AD FFL and DFL: 2008
I was working on couples of days and I am not able to authenticate with Windows AD login while users surfing the net. The Prompt was popped up, but I can't use any of account to login successfully Username and Password confirm no typo.
I was attached the config file here for /etc/squid/squid.conf:
auth_param basic program /usr/lib/squid/basic_ldap_auth -v 3 -b "ou=test,dc=victor,dc=local" -D cn=squid,ou=Users,dc=victor,dc=local -w P@ssw0rd -f sAMAccountName=%s -h ad.victor.local
auth_param basic children 5
auth_param basic realm Web-Proxy
auth_param basic credentialsttl 1 minute
acl ldap-auth proxy_auth REQUIRED
http_access allow ldap-auth
acl blocked_websites dstdomain "/etc/squid/blocked.acl"
http_access deny blocked_websites
forwarded_for off
request_header_access Allow allow all
request_header_access Authorization allow all
request_header_access WWW-Authenticate allow all
request_header_access Proxy-Authorization allow all
request_header_access Proxy-Authenticate allow all
request_header_access Cache-Control allow all
request_header_access Content-Encoding allow all
request_header_access Content-Length allow all
request_header_access Content-Type allow all
request_header_access Date allow all
request_header_access Expires allow all
request_header_access Host allow all
request_header_access If-Modified-Since allow all
request_header_access Last-Modified allow all
request_header_access Location allow all
request_header_access Pragma allow all
request_header_access Accept allow all
request_header_access Accept-Charset allow all
request_header_access Accept-Encoding allow all
request_header_access Accept-Language allow all
request_header_access Content-Language allow all
request_header_access Mime-Version allow all
request_header_access Retry-After allow all
request_header_access Title allow all
request_header_access Connection allow all
request_header_access Proxy-Connection allow all
request_header_access User-Agent allow all
request_header_access Cookie allow all
request_header_access All deny all
/var/log/squid/access.log
1728443274.790      0 172.16.100.100 TCP_DENIED/407 4100 CONNECT beacons5.gvt2.com:443 - HIER_NONE/- text/html
1728443274.791      0 172.16.100.100 TCP_DENIED/407 4100 CONNECT beacons5.gvt3.com:443 - HIER_NONE/- text/html
1728443274.792      0 172.16.100.100 TCP_DENIED/407 4108 CONNECT clients2.google.com:443 - HIER_NONE/- text/html
1728443274.792      0 172.16.100.100 TCP_DENIED/407 4100 CONNECT beacons5.gvt3.com:443 - HIER_NONE/- text/html
1728443274.793      0 172.16.100.100 TCP_DENIED/407 4100 CONNECT beacons5.gvt3.com:443 - HIER_NONE/- text/html
1728443274.794      0 172.16.100.100 TCP_DENIED/407 4108 CONNECT clients2.google.com:443 - HIER_NONE/- text/html
1728443274.795      0 172.16.100.100 TCP_DENIED/407 4108 CONNECT clients2.google.com:443 - HIER_NONE/- text/html
1728443274.795      0 172.16.100.100 TCP_DENIED/407 4108 CONNECT clients2.google.com:443 - HIER_NONE/- text/html
1728443299.708      0 172.16.100.100 TCP_DENIED/407 4106 CONNECT www.google.com:443 - HIER_NONE/- text/html
1728443303.801      0 172.16.100.100 TCP_DENIED/407 4088 CONNECT www.google.com:443 - HIER_NONE/- text/html
Any idea on it? Is there any incompatible senerio? If yes, any replacement solution?

Why is there zero information from the Active Directory server? And no packet capture?
